# OpenGL slow on windows

Tags: windows, macos, opengl, glew, glfw

i am currently writing a small game engine using OpenGL.
The mesh data is uploaded to vbos using GL_STATIC_DRAW.
Since I read that glBindBuffer is rather slow, I tried to minimize its use by accumulating the informations needed for rendering and then rendering a vbo multiple times using only one glBindBuffer per vbo (sort of like batch-rendering?).
Here is the code I use for the actual rendering:

```
    int lastID = -1;
    for(list<R_job>::iterator it = jobs.begin(); it != jobs.end(); ++it) {
        if(lastID == -1) {
            lastID = *it->vboID;
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, it->texID);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *it->vboID);
            glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 4*(3+2+3), 0);
            glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 4*(3+2+3), (void*)(4*3));
            glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 4*(3+2+3), (void*)(4*(3+2)));
        }

        if(lastID != *it->vboID) {
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, it->texID);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *it->vboID);
            glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 4*(3+2+3), 0);
            glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 4*(3+2+3), (void*)(4*3));
            glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 4*(3+2+3), (void*)(4*(3+2)));
            lastID = *it->vboID;
        }

        glPushMatrix();
        glMultMatrixf(value_ptr(*it->mat)); //the model matrix
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, it->size); //render
        glPopMatrix();
    }
```

The list is sorted by the id of the vbos. The data is interleaved.
My question is about speed. This code can render about 800 vbos (being the same, only drawArrays is called multiple times) at 30 fps on my 2010 macbook. On my PC (Phenom II X4 955 / HD 5700) at only 400 calls the fps go lower than 30. Could someone explain this to me? I hoped for a speedup on my pc. I am also using GLFW, GLEW, Xcode and VS2012 for each machine.

EDIT:
The mesh I am rendering has about 600 verts.

Comment: This may sound like a silly question, but is `it->size` defined in terms of vertex count or the size in bytes? If it is the later, then you are drawing more vertices than you actually have. GL does not generally crash when you do this (overrun your vertex array in a draw call) using VBOs, but performance will drop off a cliff.

Comment: I double checked and it->size is the number of vertices. I'll update the question with the code that creates the vbos.

Comment: Is it possible that other parts of my application are slower on windows? I am using some stl containers. But XCode time profiler says that 90% of the time is spent on glDrawArrays...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you were running in Release mode, but you might also consider running in Release mode **without the debugger attached**.  I think you will find that doing so will solve your performance issues with list::sort.  In my experience the VS debugger can make a significant performance impact when it's attached - far more so than gdb.

2000 entities is a reasonable place to start seeing some FPS drop.  At that point you are making nearly 10,000 API calls per frame.  To comfortably get higher than that, you will need to start doing something like instancing, so that you are drawing multiple entities with one call.

Finally, I would like to say that glBindBuffer is not an expensive operation, and not really something that you should be batching to avoid.  If you are going to batch, batch to avoid changing shaders and shader state (uniforms).  But don't batch just to avoid changing buffer objects.

Comment: Thanks for the informations! Though I do believe i had VC running without debugger(ctrl+F5?). If switching shader is indeed slow, I'll just batch that.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to make a 'new comment', so I'm responding to your post below.  First of all it's *very* bizarre that *enabling* VSync increased your FPS.  I don't know the details of GLFW swapBuffers (I use SDL), but something was going wrong.  VSync, in general, should always decrease framerate (because it forces buffer swap to wait for the next vertical refresh of the display).

Comment: As per the FPS drop @ 2000 entities: yes, it sounds reasonable for your graphics card. It's even more reasonable if you're doing a non-trivial amount of work in the fragment shader (more than, say, a texture sample or two). Make sure you're using mip-mapping (setting minfilter to LINEAR_MIP_LINEAR), as lots of texture sampling on non-mipmapped textures can kill FPS, especially with high-res textures. Other than that, look into instancing if you want to push higher, because you are likely experiencing driver overhead saturation at this point (too many GL calls).

Answer (score 0):

So I guess I found the answer.
Enabling VSync in AMD Control Center increased the fps greatly (probably because of GLFWs' swapBuffers), though they were still below the values of my macbook. After some debugging I found that list::sort is somehow VERY slow on windows and was pulling my fps down...

So right now(without list::sort), the fps drop(<60) at around 2000 Entities: 600*2000 = 1 200 000

Should that be my graphics cards limit?